# Unable to assign NULL to a pointer

Tags: c, cortex-m

I've got weird problem i can't explain with NULL assigment to a pointer. This is my test struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t *buffer_pntr;
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t some_other_stuff;
}my_struct_t;

void my_function (my_struct_t *handler)
{
    memset(&handler,0,sizeof(handler);
    handler->buffer_pntr=NULL;
}

void main(void)
{
   my_struct_t test;
   my_function(&test);
}
```

I want to call my_function to set my struct to a known state because i'm declaring my struct inside main so it becomes local and local variable state is unknown. Problem is that assigning NULL causes system crash(Hardfault on cortex-m4) and i'm also not sure if using memset on struct with pointer is a good practise. Removing NULL assigment from my_function and using test.buffer_pntr=NULL outside my_function solves the problem.

Comment: Note that taking a const pointer could have alerted you to the bug. Had you declared `my_struct_t * const handler`, you'd have gotten some diagnostic at the `memset`. Not to say you should go const crazy, but sometimes const correctness really pays off. For example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f998538d8ab091ff

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile.  You have unbalanced parentheses.  Is this the code you're trying to run?  If so, then it's not compiling, and you're running a stale executable.  If not, then please delete this and re-post the *actual* code.

Comment: It's also not clear what the `memset` is trying to so.  Are you trying to zero the pointer, before dereferencing it?  How do you think that will play out?

Comment: I want null pointer instead of random pointer before i initialize it to proper one to avoid call to invalid address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
memset(&handler,0,sizeof(handler));
```

I assume you want to zero the struct, but `handler` is a pointer, so when you say `&handler` you’re taking a pointer to the pointer and zeroing it. So effectively you’re doing

```
handler = NULL;
```

And then dereferencing the pointer is causing the problem. If you want to zero the structure you need to do

```
memset(handler,0,sizeof(*handler));
```

Then, of course, you don’t need to set the pointer inside to NULL separately.

Comment: @TomKarzes Oh how horrid, copy paste from original. How will I sleep at night now...

Comment: @TomKarzes Look at the time stamps. I posted 26 minutes ago. You 7 minutes ago. SO is lagging today, but not that badly... Maybe pay better attention yourself, ironically?

Answer (score 3):

```
memset(&handler,0,sizeof(handler));
```

should be

```
memset(handler,0,sizeof(*handler));
```

As `handler` is already pointer, regarding `sizeof(handler)` is size of pointer you need to pass size of object where `handler` is pointing.